# Powershell script won't launch in task scheduler when running as my admin user

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a task setup:

- Run whether logged in or not
- Run with highest privs
- When running the task use the following account (my admin account)

Program / Script: %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Arguments: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Temp\test.ps1

`test.ps1` contains:

```
Write-Host "Hello"
```

If I run this script as my normal user *without* run as highest privs, powershell launches and it works as expected.

When using the above settings though, it shows as running, then shows as completed with a result of `0x0` but powershell doesn't launch.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Note: I've tried setting the Start In to C:\Temp, I've tried various other arguments like `noprofile` `nologo` etc.

Comment: it probably runs in a different user context, so it's not visible for you. try to create a txt file in your script to see if the script really runs or not.

Comment: Good call. Will try.

Comment: Right, it is running as the file is created. So that means the script is running - it's just not visible? That shouldn't be a problem as I can write a log file to show what it's doing instead.

Comment: correct. I'm a little bit confused about "When running the task use the following account (my admin account)" - is that a different account than the one you're logged in with?

Comment: Yes, on the domain I have a normal account for everyday usage and an admin one I use when I need to do an admin task (so we don't accidentally do something because we have admin rights by default on the account we always use)

Comment: @SimonS Can you post your comment as an answer please so I can mark it as such. This would have been helpful to me as I was searching so might help someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell is running in a different user-context since you run this task as a different user than you're currently logged in. That's why you don't see any PowerShell window.

To make sure that your script really runs, try creating a txt file in your script. if it gets created, your script runs.